# in SQL Server 2014 why SELECT * FROM System_User doesn't work but SELECT * FROM [ProjectManage].[dbo].[System_User] work

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 management studio, I found a strange situation.
in a SQL query dialog, I key in the below SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM System_User
```

I can see the table name in resource management dialog is: `dbo.System_User`
Then when I try to execute it, it said there is some grammar error.

If I change the SQL as:

```
SELECT * FROM [ProjectManage].[dbo].[System_User]
```

it works well.

But acutally in same SQL query dialog, I have another SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM FlowTemplateTransition
```

and its table name is `dbo.FlowTemplateTransition` in resource management dialog.

My question is:
what is the difference between `dbo.FlowTemplateTransition` and `FlowTemplateTransition`?

when do I need to add dbo and when it is unnecessary?
do I need to using square brackets always?
Thanks

Comment: The `dbo` bit is a *schema name*, see https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/ you need to use schema names when you need to use schema names.

Answer (score 0):

dbo is the default schema in SQL Server. You can create your own schemas to allow you to better manage your object namespace.

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can create your own schema by browsing to Databases - Your Database - Security - Schemas. Or you can execute below query to create a schema.

```
CREATE SCHEMA [SchemaName] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
```

You can use them to logically group your tables, for example by creating a schama for "vendors" information and another for "customers" data. Your tables would then display as:

```
vendors.BankAccounts 
vendors.Transactions 
customers.Address
```

Instead of using the default schema of dbo.

No need to use the square brackets[] always. But if your database or table name contains something like a dot(.) then you must use [].

Comment: Do you know why in same database, [ProjectManage], and in same SQL query dialog. one table FlowTemplateTransition can work by SQL 'SELECT * FROM FlowTemplateTransition' but one table System_User does not by SQL 'SELECT * FROM System_User'. they are should be in same way.

Comment: Yes. Because SYSTEM_USER is a keyword in SQL server use to return the current system user name. If you type "select System_User" it will return the name of the user currently logged in. So if you have a table in the same name, you have to use []. "select * from [System_User]" then only SQL server will identify it as a table

Comment: @ZhangPingfeng If the answer helped solve your problem, you might want to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have 3 questions. I have list it down separately.

1. Why `SELECT * FROM System_User` not working?
2. what is the difference between `dbo.FlowTemplateTransition` and `FlowTemplateTransition`
3. when do I need to add dbo and when it is unnecessary? do I need to using square brackets always?

Answer 1 : `System_User` is sql server built in function. Your table name conflict with this function that is why it gives an error.

Answer 2 : `dbo` is default database owner. If you don't write owner of table than Sql Server automatically consider `dbo` as an owner for that table.

Answer 3 : Generally `dbo` is not necessary to add.
The brackets are required if you use keywords or special chars in the table name.